# Change the KeyboardType to a Number Pad with Decimal point for Settings Preferences

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, plist

I am currently implementing Root.plist for the Settings Preferences.
I want to make a Text Field Element (PSTextFieldSpecifier) with input keyboard as NumberPad with a Decimal Point.

I tried to put "KeyboardType  NumberPad" in the plist, however the iPhone 4.3 Simulator's NumberPad doesn't have the Decimal Point.
I also tried to "KeyboardType  DecimalPad" and "KeyboardType NumbersAndPunctuation" but it didn't work.

Is there a KeyboardType that will show a Numberpad with a decimal point?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a number pad keyboard with decimal point is not available.

Comment: sorry to disagree, you'll find there's a UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad

Comment: @ Elland: Read the question again.

Answer (score -1):

Set the keyboard type manually (as in programmatically) to `UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad`.

Example:

```
[self.priceTextField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad];
```

Comment: This works on a UITextField, but not in the Settings bundle which the OP's question was about.